# How to change values in array which meet criteria via JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a big JSON data, this is a small part:

```
users = [{
  "name": "alex", 
   "id":123, 
   "surname":"xx",
   "status":"activated",  
    tarriff: {
      "id":1,
      "name":"free"
    }
},
 {
  "name": "tom", 
   "id":124, 
   "surname":"henry",
   "status":"activated", 
    tarriff: {
      "id":1,
      "name":"free"
    }
},
 {
  "name": "tom", 
   "id":125, 
   "surname":"henry",
   "status":"archived",  
    tarriff: {
      "id":1,
      "name":"free"
    }
}]
```

I need to change value `'activated'` to `'deactivated'`, `'archived'` to `'active'` in whole array. 
I think I need to use `for` loop, but I don't know how to properly write it.

Comment: `I think I need to use for loop, but I don't know how to properly write it.`. `users.forEach(user => { /*... */ })`.

Comment: Use [array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to accomplish this

Comment: Please do some research, try a few things, then come back and ask your question, providing your research and attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Array` prototype `map` function :

```
users = users.map(function(u) {
  if (u.status == 'activated') u.status = 'deactivated'
  if (u.status == 'archived') u.status = 'active'
  return u
})
```

---

**Update**. A faster approach.

```
var counter, item;
for (counter in users) {
  item = users[counter];
  if (item.status == 'activated') item.status = 'deactivated'
  if (item.status == 'archived') item.status = 'active'
}
```

You cannot do it faster or more narrow.

Comment: @Hitmands I really do not understand your point...? Can see you are using `map` as well, is the return of a whole new `Object` not just an unnecessary time and ram consuming overhead?

Comment: `users = users.map(...)` is an unnecessary time and ram consuming if you then modify the object in place.

Comment: @Hitmands, please explain. Can you point to any articles proving that?

Comment: can you explain why you are reassigning a new reference to `users`? What does it change in your script if you don't reassign it? or if you use `forEach` instead of `map`?

Comment: @Hitmands, OK, now I see what you mean. It was just by coincidence, normally (myself) I like to preserve the original array as reference and have the (most likely heavily reduced) modified dataset the DOM have to work with in another variable, like "`displayUsers`". It was a good observation that `users =` not is necessary in this particular case.

Comment: @Hitmands, yes, you could use a `for x in y` loop instead, probably the fastest

Answer (score 1):

Try the following with array's `map()`.

```js
var users = [{
  "name": "alex", 
   "id":123, 
   "surname":"xx",
   "status":"activated",  
    tarriff: {
      "id":1,
      "name":"free"
    }
},
 {
  "name": "tom", 
   "id":124, 
   "surname":"henry",
   "status":"activated", 
    tarriff: {
      "id":1,
      "name":"free"
    }
},
 {
  "name": "tom", 
   "id":125, 
   "surname":"henry",
   "status":"archived",  
    tarriff: {
      "id":1,
      "name":"free"
    }
}];

var res = users.map(function(item){
  if(item.status == 'activated')
    item.status = 'deactivated';
  if(item.status == 'archived')
    item.status = 'active';
  return item;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: use `Array#forEach` then.

Comment: But, you are mutating the source array @Mamun

Answer (score 1):

this is a possible way ([`Array#extras`](https://www.sitepoint.com/back-to-basics-array-extras/)):

```js
function changeUserStatus(status) {
  // 'activated' to 'deactivated', 'archived' to 'active'
  
  switch (status) {
    case 'activated':
      return 'deactivated';
      
    case 'archived':
      return 'active';
    
    default:
      return status;
  }
}

function changeStatus(users) {
  return users.map(function(user) {
    
    return Object.assign({}, user, {
      status: changeUserStatus(user.status),
    });
  });
}

var users = [{
  "name": "alex", 
   "id":123, 
   "surname":"xx",
   "status":"activated",  
    tarriff: {
      "id":1,
      "name":"free"
    }
},
 {
  "name": "tom", 
   "id":124, 
   "surname":"henry",
   "status":"activated", 
    tarriff: {
      "id":1,
      "name":"free"
    }
},
 {
  "name": "tom", 
   "id":125, 
   "surname":"henry",
   "status":"archived",  
    tarriff: {
      "id":1,
      "name":"free"
    }
}];

const edited = changeStatus(users);

console.log('edited', edited);
```

Comment: You are eager to critizice other peoples answers, but have you looked into the cost of creating a whole new `Object` for each iteration? And when you `return` you are in fact creating a new scope instance as well, i.e "mutating". Your way is not particular bad, it is just not different from the pure `map` solutions, you just create a new scope in the return of the function.

Comment: it is completely different and allows you to have old and new states... It is the principle of functional programming...

Comment: BS :) You lack the understanding of how a JS engine work. You do exactly the same, just more elaborated. And using `map` *and* implicit `new Object` will be extremely slow on large set of literals / JSON ...

Comment: from a developer to a developer, your tone isn't constructive... and you would have certainly understand my point of view if you were (enough) open to different opinions...

Comment: :) Hillarious With +5000 rep you should have better understanding and be able to slide off conflicts. You criticize me for doing something yourself are doing and suggesting, just even worse. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRfF7W4El60 EOD

Comment: I didn't say "You lack the understanding", while you effectively do saying buggy code is preferable because it is faster... regardless of the amount of data, you should always ship good code.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know if your intentions about to mutate original object or just return a new array of objects. But below code might give you an inspiration.

```
function changeValue(obj, k, vold, vnew) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k) && obj[k] == vold) {
      obj[k] = vnew 
  }
  return obj;
}
```

then,

```
users
  .map(e => changeValue(e, 'status', 'activated', 'deactivated'))
  .map(e => changeValue(e, 'status', 'archived', 'active'));
```